# Should I use begin tran to do an alter table column that increases the column length?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, transaction, alter-table

I want to execute this statement in a production database to alter the length of a varchar column from 50 to 72:

```
ALTER TABLE Users ALTER COLUMN LoginID varchar(72) NOT NULL
```

The column is not null so I'm NOT altering column nullability from NULL to NOT NULL.

Database server is SQL Server 2008 R2; table has about 60,000 records.

Do I have to put the alter statment within begin tran commit tran?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement is atomic and is its own transaction, so no, there is no value in surrounding it with `BEGIN TRANSACTION; / COMMIT TRANSACTION;`. It will either succeed in whole or fail in whole.

Comment: Also it will try to take a full table lock for the duration, so other transactions will either block until it is finished or may block it from proceeding until they are finished with their locks on that resource.

Comment: I would say there is some value putting in the begin and end tran in that it's explicit vs implied so that others reading your code aren't wondering if it's in a transaction or not.

Comment: @StarShip3000 any single statement is an atomic operation - no single statement can partially commit or rollback. I don't really comprehend what value you think it adds to wrap them; by extension do you think you should wrap every single statement not already involved in a larger transaction with BEGIN TRANSACTION / COMMIT TRANSACTION? Do you also name your tables `tblWhatever` so that nobody can get confused about them not being tables, or a column `intCustomerID` in case someone might assume that it's `char` or some other data type? I'm all for self-documenting code, within reason.

Comment: I honestly don't see how you can't comprehend this. I work in a shop with a mix of DBA and developers of various database skill. We have found that having code templates that cover all cases to be the best. So in our case having BEGIN and END trans for all DML templates works best because if they add more than one DDL to the script it will all fail or succeed and the template keeps us from dealing with people coming up with clever solutions to a simple problem.

Comment: @StarShip3000 so if you have a stored procedure that does 5 independent things, you have 5 BEGIN / COMMIT wrappers? Does it also have proper error handling and ROLLBACK conditionals for each of the 5 statements? The question asked if a single statement *needed* begin / commit wrappers, not if he *should* use them because his team is likely to later change the code and not understand that that single statement was an atomic transaction.

Comment: Typically my stored procedures would be atomic unless I'm doing a batch commit moving large volumes of data around.

Comment: @StarShip3000 let's keep to the scope of the question, instead of changing its meaning for *your* scenario.

Comment: No, I'm in scope I said there is some non-technical benefit to adding begin and end tran even if technically it's not needed.

Comment: @StarShip3000 the part of the question I focused on was in the body, not the title: `do I have to` - if you think there is some benefit that the OP isn't considering, add an answer or a comment of your own. But remember that what you're suggesting is very largely an opinion thing - I suspect most people won't want to litter every single statement with BEGIN / COMMIT wrappers, never mind all the error handling and other scaffolding, because they don't trust their users to change their code correctly in the future.

Comment: I can read rather well. "Should I use begin tran to do an alter table.." +1 to your answer as it's correct I was just trying to add a little side information, good day.